# Set up React Native children component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I trying to send data trough the props from parent component to children in React Native.
`Parent Component`

```js
<Card>
  <CardSection>
    <Input
      proportion={5}
      label="Email"
    />
  </CardSection>
  <CardSection>
    <Input
      proportion={3}
      label="Password"
    />
  </CardSection>
</Card>
```

`Children Component`

```js
const Input = ({ proportion, label }) => {
  const { inputStyle } = styles;
  inputStyle.flex = proportion;

  return (
    <View style={containerStyle}>
      <Text>{label}</Text>
      <TextInput style={inputStyle} />
    </View>
  );
};

const style = {
  inputStyle: {
    flex: 2
  }
};
```

And I've got error `You attempted set the key 'flex' with the value '3' on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen`. Interesting fact, when I've one `<Input /> Component` everything works fine and set `flex: 5`, and I reach what I wanted, but with second `<Input /> Component` I've got error. How I can fix this and set properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the good way is to use object spread operator:

```
const Input = ({ proportion, label }) => {
  const { inputStyle } = styles;

  return (
    <View style={containerStyle}>
      <Text>{label}</Text>
      <TextInput style={{...inputStyle, flex: proportion}} />
    </View>
  );
};

const style = {
  inputStyle: {
    flex: 2
  }
};
```

You define style like const, so you get an error. You can also define it like variable by let.

Comment: another way in RN would be `style={[inputStyle, { flex: proportion }]}`

Comment: @madox2, Your option gives me exactly what I need, thanks man